# Get neighborhood of a starting node ArangoDB

Tags: graph, arangodb, vertex

I'm using ArangoDB 3.2.25. I want to extract neighbors from  a starting node.

Here is what I tried:

```
FOR x IN  1..1
ANY "vert1/5001"  Col_edge_L 
RETURN x
```

but I'm getting missing vert2.

Here is the schema of the collection

```
  {"_from":"vert1/560","_to":"vert2/5687768","id":771195,"score":218}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you do in your query is to start at the vertex with key `5001` from the collection `vert1` and follow all edges stored in collection `Col_edge_L` in any direction (so `_from` or `_to` equal to `vert1/5001`).

If there are edges in `Col_edge_L` like

```
{ "_from": "vert1/5001", "_to": "vert1/789" }
{ "_from": "vert2/44", "_to": "vert1/5001" }
```

then the result should be:

```
[
    { "_id": "vert2/44", ... },
    { "_id": "vert1/789", ... }
]
```

Exception: if the vertex collections exist, but not the vertices referenced in the `_from` and `_to` properties of the edges, the traversal will work but return *null* for the missing vertices (`x` variable).

The edge you posted in your question does not reference the starting vertex `vert1/5001`, so it wouldn't be followed and no vertex returned from this edge. If you miss vertices in the result, there might simply be no edges that link the starting vertex to another document.